# Can roads in neutral territory be pillaged or destroyed?

Tags: civilization-5

Roads in my territory are destroyed with a worker.

Roads in enemy territory are destroyed using pillage with a military unit.

Can roads in neutral territory be pillaged or destroyed?

**Additional: Worker options on a neutral road hex.**
[image]

**Additional: Military options on a neutral road hex.**
[image]

### **Additional: Military options on a neutral ruins and road hex!**

Cannot remove road on a ruins hex. Unsure if removing road around that hex is the answer.
Far out, I decide to remove road on the one hex which was a ruins!
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can pillage them with a military unit.  You do not earn any gold for pillaging roads in neutral territory.

The one exception is the "ruins" object which is created when a city is razed.
[image]

Comment: I have updated the OP with a screen shot of a worker with their Build Actions. Is it a keyboard shortcut I need to use?

Comment: @Valamas Sorry, you do need to use a military unit, because workers can't pillage.

Comment: I have updated my OP. It appears you cannot remove road from a hex which had a city (Ruins). Feel free to update your answer which I will then mark as correct.